# generalization of Dyck Path: size K upward steps

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-geometry, geometric-probability, catalan-numbers

One of the many interpretations of Dyck Paths is the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$, staying at or below the diagonal $y=x$, using only 2 kinds of line segments (1 unit right, or 1 unit up).

Dyck Paths from Wolfram Mathworld:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DyckPath.html

The number of Dyck Paths is given by the Catalan numbers.

---

My question is, if we generalize this so that the 2 allowed types of line segments are ($1$ unit to the right) and ($K$ units upward), now how many "K-Dyck paths" are possible?

Can we further generalize this to allow $K+1$ kinds of step types: ($1$ unit right) vs. (any of $1, 2, \ldots, K$ units upward)?

Comment: I know that there is a nice answer for paths which go one unit up or $k$ units right at each step. This is equivalent to paths which go up or right one step, staying at or above $y=kx$. See http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Classes/Four_Proofs_of_Ballot_Theorem.pdf (you want the weak version at the end).